# How do I use Videojs with RTSP in React?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, video-streaming, rtsp, video.js

I have searched for a solution on how to use Videojs with RTSP for live streaming in React but most of the solutions are outdated so I had to ask this question again.
I am using Next.js and this is my `Stream` component:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import videojs from "video.js";

export default function Stream() {
    const videoRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (videoRef.current) {
            videojs(videoRef.current, {
                sources: [
                    {
                        src: "rtsp://...",
                    }
                ]
            });
        }
    });

    return (
        <video controls ref={videoRef} className="video-js" />
    );
}
```

And this is how I use it

```
<div>
    <Stream />
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your current implementation?

Comment: You can't - RTSP can't be played in a browser. You'll need to convert to HLS

Comment: @juliomalves yes. nothing is being played. Seems like there is no way to play rtsp in browser

Comment: @misterben HLS has a large delay. Is there a faster way to do it? I've read about webRTC and how it can give you 500ms delay.